# Automatic Rsync on samba share server

Tags: cron, rsync, samba, fstab

**Problem**:

I just cannot make it work. I have set up my samba share server on fstab with the following command:

```
//192.168.178.145/Rsync_Dell /mnt/Rsync_Dell cifs credentials=/home/Alessio/.smbcredentials,uid=1001,gid=100 0 0
```

where .smbcredentials stores username,password and domain name.

I saved the rsync job using the command `sudo crontab -e -u root`
the job in crontab is :

`0 1-23 * * 0 sudo rsync -azEo --delete-delay /home/Alessio/ /mnt/Rsync_Dell/  --exclude=".*"`

The job will not work. More specifically the pc does not mount correctly the samba share server and when it does run the job it just backs up to the local filesystem under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:domain=WORKGROUP...` and not on the Windows share. I have tested the mount and it correctly mounts but fstab seems to not understand the correct path.

**Additional information:**

```
Distro info:
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.2 Tina
Release:    19.2
Codename:   tina
```

Information retrieved in the file `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cron.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Regular background program processing daemon
Documentation=man:cron(8)
    
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/cron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
KillMode=process
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Is the share mounted? (It's not been set up to automount so it will only mount at boot or when you type `mount /mnt/Rsync_Dell`)

Comment: Yesterday I run the command from the terminal checking the verbose returns, I made sure the server was mounted, it seems again to direct to local directories! Funny thing is that I cannot spot where it is actually doing the rsync to in my local pc. To repeat the issue, this rsync is not sending files to the server at all.

Comment: Remove the `sudo` from the crontab entry. You're editing root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e -u root`) so there's no point in telling root to run `sudo` to become root.

Comment: Simplify your `-azEo` to `-a` (the other flags are already implied by `-a` or have no effect when copying between two local filesystem trees)

Comment: Same partition as per Home partition since the free space gets reduced with time when executing the command.

Comment: However when browse /mnt/Rsync_Dell I correctly browse my server since it shows the storage space of my server device.

Comment: it seems it sends files to /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:domain=WORKGROUP..... that was the result given by disk usage analyzer.

Comment: That's strange. It's like your cron service has been configured with a filesystem mask, which I really wouldn't expect. What Linux distribution are you running? Can you please add the contents of `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cron.service` to your question

Comment: Command not found. However yesterday's result was via a regular terminal command.

Comment: I have added the information in the Question. Thank you for all the instructions and time spent.